# AspectJ pointcut on method in Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, interface, aspectj, crud, pointcut

I'm using Spring's `CrudRepository` in combination with the annotation `@RepositoryRestResource` to implement a simple CRUD-app that can be used throught a RESTful API. I now want to add an **AspectJ pointcut on my repository**, so that some functionalities will be executed whenever a CRUD-method from the interface is called.

First, I extend Spring's `CrudRepository` to add some custom functionalities in my own interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "customers", path = "customers")
public interface CustomerRestRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer>{
   Customer findOneByGuid(@Param("customerGuid") String customerGuid);
   //Other custom methods.
}
```

Everything is working fine and I'm able to call this method via my REST client. I do not have to implement the interface `CustomerRestRepository` since Spring is doing the job as a miracle in behind. This is one of the crucial advantages of extending Springs's `CrudRepository`.

The problem, I'm facing now, is to **add an AspectJ pointcut on** this custom **method `findOneByGuid()`** that will, for example, log every call of the method after it's execution.

What I've tried by so far is:

```
@Aspect
public aspect AfterCustomerCrudAspect {
   @Pointcut(
        "execution(* com.x.y.z.CustomerRestRepository.findOneByGuid(..))")
   public void customerCrudMethod() {}

   @AfterReturning("customerCrudMethod()")
   public void doSomething() {
      //Do something
   }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
1) execution(* com.x.y.z.CustomerRestRepository+.findOneByGuid(..))
2) execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))
3) within(com.x.y.z.CustomerRestRepository)
4) annotation(RepositoryRestResource)
```

...and many others I do not remember. All with the same frustrating result: The advice is never applied.

By the way, I do not face any exceptions and if I try `execution(* *.*(..))`, the advice is working well - but, of course, not limited to the method `findOneByGuid()`. Thus, I think my code is correct in general.

I know that it is not possible to set pointcuts on interfaces. But since I do not have to implement the interface `CustomerRestRepository` by my own to get things working, I need to find a way to set a pointcut on an interface's method - or to find some other solution.

Well, one possible solution to that would be to implement the interface `CustomerRestRepository`. But then I've to do all the implementation work for the repository by my own and skip using the advantages of Spring's `CrudRepository`.

Thus, **my question** is, if there is a **possibility to set a AspectJ pointcut on methods in a Spring `CrudRepository`**.

Many thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: This is the only use-case I can think of when it's better to use Spring AOP instead of AspectJ. Spring AOP should fit nicely into Spring's own proxying infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I solved my problem in a different way.

Sometimes, things are less complicated than expected. Adding an AspectJ pointcut on a Spring CRUD-repository to execute some functionalities, whenever an entity is changed was not the best idea. (And at the best of my knowledge, it is not possible at all.)

There is a much more easier way to implement my requirement: The package `javax.persistence` provides the annotation `@EntityListeners` that suites perfectly to this job. So, annotate the entity class with the listener and implement the needed functionalities within the listener class:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(CustomerEntityListener.class)
//@Table, @NamedQueries and other stuff ...
public class Customer implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Implementation of the `EntityListener`:

```
public class CustomerEntityListener {
   @PostPersist
   public void customerPostPersist(Customer customer) {
      //Add functionalities
   }
}
```

The `EntityListener`also provides annotation for `@PostUpdate`, `@PostRemove` and so on - [visit this site for more information](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove).